# XML parsing is not working when it's only one array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xml-parsing

I am parsing the xml like following:

```
$result = '
<sms>
<status>0</status>
<message>
<contact_lists>
<contact_list><cl_id>11111</cl_id><phone>999999999</phone><name>Neu</name></contact_list>
<contact_list><cl_id>222222</cl_id><phone>888888888</phone><name>Alt</name></contact_list>
</contact_lists>
</message>
</sms>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,true);

$contact_lists = $array['contact_lists']['contact_list'];
```

`A` sometimes the array look like this, which is works.

```
Array ( [status] => 0 [message] => Array ( ) [contact_lists] => Array ( [contact_list] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [cl_id] => 11111 [phone] => 999999999 [name] => Neu ) [1] => Array ( [cl_id] => 222222 [phone] => 888888888 [name] => Alt ) ) ) )
```

`B` but sometime if the array has only one contact_list, it will look like following

```
Array ( [status] => 0 [message] => Array ( ) [contact_lists] => Array ( [contact_list] => Array ( [cl_id] => 11111 [phone] => 999999999 [name] => Neu ) ) )
```

when i use `$contact_lists`in foreach loop it works with `A` since there are multiple array keys like 0,1,2,etc... but with `B` it shows error `Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' etc..` since there are no array key like 0,1,2,etc...

so parsing the xml is automatically removing the key numbering which causing the the issue.

1- is there a way to keep the key numbering if only one array?

2- tried to use `if (count($contact_lists) >= 1) {` , but its not working as well..

Any idea for a workaround to solve such issue ?

**SOLUTION:**

```
$contact_lists_found = isset($array['contact_lists']['contact_list']) ? $array['contact_lists']['contact_list'] : '';

    
    if ($contact_lists_found !== '' ) {

        if (array_key_exists('0', $contact_lists_found)) {
            // more than contact list
            $contact_lists = $array['contact_lists']['contact_list'];
        } else {
            // only one contact list
            $contact_lists[0] = $array['contact_lists']['contact_list'];
        }
        
    } else {
        
        $contact_lists = array();
    }
```

Comment: The problem is more likely that you don't process the XML, but you mangle the data by passing it through json.  If you learnt how to process it using SimpleXML, then you can probably control the extract better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just check, if the key `0` is set, and if not, then simply overwrite the element `contact_list` with itself wrapped into an array:

```
if(!isset($array['message']['contact_lists']['contact_list'][0])) {
  $array['message']['contact_lists']['contact_list'] = [
    $array['message']['contact_lists']['contact_list']
  ];
}
```

`0` is not a valid tag name in XML, so you should never get that, unless there was more than one `<contact_list>` in the XML.

Comment: i fixed it with some ideas from your answer. i search the array instead. solution added to the post. Thanks